# List access request email of users in SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 there is a url to view pending requests but I can't find the same in 2010.

Is there a way I can find out the emails as I would like to remove them?Especially people that have left the company and the email is still coming through.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is not too much control in SharePoint 2010, it is manual process to change the email address on which access request received.

To change:

- Go to Site Settings
- choose Site permissions under Users and Permissions section.
- Manage Access Requests is exposed in the ribbon like this
  [image]

Clicking on Manage Access Requests 
[image]

Change here

Source: [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2011/03/15/want-to-use-manage-access-requests-feature-in-sharepoint-2010/)